# How to decode this data in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm at a loss with attempting to decode this data using JSON.

This is the data returned from URL. It can be cached or something, it changes like once a year :)

> [{"service_type":"1","price":"0,62","money_added":"0,31","value":"70068","type":"TTL.X50"},{"service_type":"2","price":"1,23","money_added":"0,61","value":"71068","type":"TTL.X100"},{"service_type":"3","price":"2,46","money_added":"1,22","value":"72068","type":"TTL.X200"},{"service_type":"4","price":"3,69","money_added":"1,80","value":"73068","type":"TTL.X300"},{"service_type":"5","price":"4,92","money_added":"2,45","value":"74068","type":"TTL.X400"},{"service_type":"6","price":"6,15","money_added":"3,05","value":"75068","type":"TTL.X500"},{"service_type":"7","price":"7,38","money_added":"3,65","value":"76068","type":"TTL.X600"},{"service_type":"8","price":"11,07","money_added":"5,50","value":"79068","type":"TTL.X900"},{"service_type":"11","price":"12,30","money_added":"6,10","value":"91058","type":"TTL.X10"},{"service_type":"12","price":"20,91","money_added":"10,40","value":"91758","type":"TTL.X170"},{"service_type":"9","price":"23,37","money_added":"11,60","value":"91958","type":"TTL.X190"},{"service_type":"13","price":"24,60","money_added":"12,20","value":"92058","type":"TTL.X20"},{"service_type":"10","price":"30,75","money_added":"15,80","value":"92578","type":"TTL.X250"}]

How can I make it accessible easily like from a function? I attempted to deserialize JSON using the "newtonsoft" but I failed really badly.

Any help would be really greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "failed really badly?" JSON.Net should be able to deserialize this fine.

Comment: What did your code look like that was trying to deserialize that string?

Comment: You should be including [the code that you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) as part of your question.

Comment: `I failed really badly.` What did you try? What did not work? What exception did you get?

Comment: Agent Smith, while adding sample make sure to check http://sscce.org/ to provide a good one...

Comment: The JSON itself looks fine.  We need some code examples of what you've tried, to help you fix whatever isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var services = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Service>>(yourjson);
```

```
public class Service
{
    public string service_type { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string money_added { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you! How would I actually call the function? Like I want to pass it value and get service type.